# Unexpected Eclipse m2e fetched dependencies newer than my source

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Is there a better way to work with eclipse & maven than setting eclipse's maven prefs to **offline** and using maven command line when I want to fetch dependencies?

Eclipse + maven via m2e downloads binaries that are out of sync with my source.

While working on a bug I want to control when I pull in source and dependencies to my eclipse workspace.   However, my continuous integration system is always building new snapshots for me to fetch.  Sometimes eclipse will fetch dependencies which break my local build because I haven't (and don't want to) update source quite yet.

Is there a trick I'm missing or is this optimal for those who want to be less than continuously integrated?

- set eclipse Window -> Preference -> Maven to **offline**
- update from source control
- build on command line with maven
- work in eclipse: change, test, ponder, repeat
- when ready to receive changes: update source, mvn build on command line and return to eclipse

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an option for you, you can checkout the SNAPSHOT dependencies of your project into your workspace and enable "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects" in your project settings.
With this solution you can control when to get the new sources of your dependencies without all the disadvantages of putting Maven offline.

Comment: Unless I don't wish to include 20 plus projects.  Still,  a good option and the default i think.